# Send multiple objects of same class from jsp to spring controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

When i am keeping two inputs name same in jsp. I want they should be come to controller in two different objects. @ModelAttribut

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAdvertiser(@ModelAttribute("userInfoEntity") UserInfoEntity userInfoEntity,@ModelAttribute("addressEntity") AddressEntity personalAddress,@ModelAttribute("addressEntity") AddressEntity billingAddress){
// save this two address to my userInfo Entity 
// here i had one to many relationaship. from UserInfoEntity to AddressEntity
}
```

My JSP is as follows:

```
Personal Address
<div class="label"><b>Address 1 :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="address1" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>City :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="city" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Zipcode :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="zipcode" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Address 2 :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="address2" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>State :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="state" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Phone :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="phone" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>




Billing Address
                        <div class="label"><b>Address 1 :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="address1" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>City :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="city" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Zipcode :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="zipcode" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Address 2 :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="address2" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>State :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="state" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>

                        <div class="label"><b>Phone :</b></div>
                        <div class="leftSide"><input type="text" name="phone" class="textBox" style="width:250px;" /></div>
```

Please tell me the solution that how can i send two objects of same AddressEntity from jsp to controller keeping the same value for attribute "name" of input type.

In the given senario i am getting the object but it includes values of both address by ","(comma) seperated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find it in documentation, just read section about nesting properties.

For provided case you need to set field names properly:

```
user.address[0].city
user.address[1].city
user.address[2].city
```

and same for the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is same, **it will return you an array of objects**, that's why when you try to print it, it shows string with comma separation.

> You need to cast object to array of your return type ( probably
>   string in your case ). and get values arr[0] and arr[1].

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can't i get the two different objects of AddressEntity class in controller...

Comment: can i get two or multiple different address objects in controller from jsp.

Comment: Yes but they should be set to different properties on jsp

Comment: actually i didnt get array for long values from jsp to controller. they only return single value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `AddressDataBean` as follows.

```
public class AddressDataBean {
    private Address personalAddress;
    private Address billingAddress;

    // Getters and Setters for the properties;
}
```

And Address class as below.

```
public class Address {
    // All the address fields those are in your jsp.

    // Getters and setters for the fields.
}
```

In your jsp you need to use the spring form taglib and bind the both personalAddress fields and billingAddress fields.

eg.  and

And in the controller you need to define AddressDataBean as @ModelAttribute.

**EDIT**

You can have the personalAddress and billingAddress properties in your **UserInfoEntity** bean. I realised it later. :)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually there can be multiple billing addresses to the one User. and what should i write in jsp to get the address values in controller.

Comment: can i get two or multiple different address objects in controller from jsp.

Comment: If you are not sure about the number of billing Addresses then you can use LazyList for billingAddress and it will allow you to have as many as billingAddress you want runtime. But if you have specific number of billingAddresses only then you can use simple list but you need to initialize it before you use it in jsp.

Comment: please tell me that what name should be given for input type text in jsp for multiples address fields.like city will be in all the address. if i declare city as name for input field then it won't work. Please help me.

Comment: You need to give the names like `billingAddress.city` and `personalAddress.city`.