# Send multiple of same object to Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on a quiz app. I want to the user to be able to create a quiz with 10 questions (although I am open to this being variable length). If I create more than 1 question with @ModelAttribute, instead of getting more than 1 QuestionAnswerInfo objects, I get one with each field separated by commas. This does not seem to be a List, but simply Strings separated by commas.

I want each question to come in and be handled separately. **What is the best way to approach this?**

This is the best answer I have found but I can't seem to make sense of it in my context: [Send multiple objects of same class from jsp to spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135009/send-multiple-objects-of-same-class-from-jsp-to-spring-controller)

Models
(Abstract Entity is just ID generation)

```
@Entity
public class Quiz extends AbstractEntity {

    public String name;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_question_foreign_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<QuestionAnswerInfo> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Quiz(){}

    public Quiz(String name, ArrayList<QuestionAnswerInfo> questions)  {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
//Getters and Setters

}

@Entity
public class QuestionAnswerInfo extends AbstractEntity{

    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private String questionType;
    private String additionalAnswerInfo;

    public QuestionAnswerInfo (){}

    public QuestionAnswerInfo(String question, String answer, String questionType, String additionalAnswerInfo) {
        super();
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.questionType = questionType;
        this.additionalAnswerInfo = additionalAnswerInfo;
    }

//Getters and Setters
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class QuizController {

    //Repositories

    @RequestMapping("create")
    public String displayCreateNewQuiz(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Quiz());
        model.addAttribute("questions", new QuestionAnswerInfo());
        return "create";
    }

    @PostMapping("create")
    public String processCreateNewQuiz(@ModelAttribute Quiz newQuiz, @ModelAttribute QuestionAnswerInfo questions,
                                       Model model) {
        newQuiz.getQuestions().add(questions);
        quizRepository.save(newQuiz);
        return "index";
    }
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Create a Quiz</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label th:for="name">Quiz Name</label>
        <input th:field="${quiz.name}"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <div>
        <label th:for="question">Add a Question</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.question}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="answer">Add an Answer</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.answer}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="questionType">Question Type</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.questionType}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="additionalAnswerInfo">Add Additional Information</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.additionalAnswerInfo}"/>
    </div>

    <p>Question 2</p>
    <div>
        <label th:for="question">Add a Question</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.question}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="answer">Add an Answer</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.answer}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="questionType">Question Type</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.questionType}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label th:for="additionalAnswerInfo">Add Additional Information</label>
        <input th:field="${questions.additionalAnswerInfo}"/>
    </div>



    <input type="submit" value="Create Quiz"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I will eventually have a similar problem with collecting User answers when they take the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `js` to handle multiple questions so that in the request there will be list of questions in the request body.

Comment: I am only a few months info programming. Can you be more specific in what I need to do? Thanks!